# Good back-office solution in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

is there a ready solution (gem, plugin...) to quickly have a back-office for a mostly static website?
It should be a bit more user-friendly than admin-data.

Thanks,
Augusto

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'back-office'. Elaborate?

Comment: There is a mostly static website with a "products" section.
I want to give the admin the possibility to add new products, edit existing ones, associate some images and a location to an existing product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try, in order of rising backend complexity (but also increasing frontend userfriendliness):

https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage

https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/

http://refinerycms.com/

http://www.locomotivecms.com/

Comment: These seems great but more focused on editing pages of a website.
I need something more specific, managing the product database of the site.

Comment: OK.  I don't have any experience with it, but the http://hobocentral.net/ framework seems to promise such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

If by "back-office", you mean a [Content Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) type of system, then I've heard very good things about [Radiant](http://radiantcms.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Typus always worked for me:
[Typus](https://github.com/fesplugas/typus)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Forest Admin](https://www.forestadmin.com/). They will allow you get an up and running back-office in minutes. They have all the standard features you need so you will be able to easily perform CRUD actions for your data models.